# Clear to int value (DbNull.Value)

Tags: c#, sql, dbnull

I want to change column value to DbNull.Value,

I tried; `stokIst.IstasyonId = DBNull.Value;`

stokIst not a primary key but its int column. I want to clear the value in the column as the target. When I save it at first, this value seems clear. an assignment is made later and may need to be cleared again later.

Comment: Does your `IstasyonId` column allow `NULL` in your database?

Comment: yes, but i fixed thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592684/13580572

```
//cast
private int? IstasyonId;
public object ID {
    get
    {
        return IstasyonId.HasValue ? IstasyonId.Value as object : DBNull.Value;    
    }
}
//code
stokIst.IstasyonId =IstasyonId;
```